# What WPF control should I inherit from?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls

I've written a WPF control which accepts a number of UIElement objects as input and displays them docked either vertically or horizontally. The control exposes functions for enumerating, removing and inserting children, but internally I'm using a Grid to build the layout, creating a row/column for each item and inserting a GridSplitter between them. To do this I've inherited from ContentControl, and upon initialization I just set the Content property with the Grid. Everything is working as intended, but now I wonder if this might be confusing for the user of my control, as it would be counter-intuitive to have a ContentControl that has many items.

Should I be inheriting from ItemsControl instead? 
Should I inherit directly from Control which is "content-agnostic"? 
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) - basically a control which is responsible for the layout of many elements. I would consider inheriting from that.

Comment: Agreed.  Panel has the added benefit of accepting any number of children rather than only a single child like ContentControl.

Answer (score 0):

Your mention of "docked either vertically or horizontally" leads me to believe perhaps a [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) would be a better fit, since it does docking as well.